# Decode function for selecting Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, decode

Is there any (same or alternate) way of using Table names with the `DECODE` function.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
DECODE(FLAG,1,TABLE1,2,TABLE2,TABLE3)
```

Comment: http://psoug.org/reference/decode_case.html

Answer (score 2):

In SQL the table names cannot be determined at the run time. They need to be provided at the compile time.

If you need to provide the table names dynamically, you will need to use Dynamic SQL.

Hope it Helps

Vishad

Comment: @Abhinav: Don't think there is any scenario where the table names in the `from` clause can be determined at the run time. Let me know in case i missed something.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 where decode(flag, 1,1,      0) = 1 union
select * from table2 where decode(flag, 2,1,      0) = 1 union
select * from table3 where decode(flag, 1,0, 2,0, 1) = 1;
```